# Conditional logic if column cell is null

Tags: javascript

I want to loop through rows on a table and only execute a change background color if `column2` cells contain no values or empty cells. This is what I have now but all my rows are colored and I only need the logic applied when cells in `column2` are empty.

JS:

```
// loops through rows
for (var i = 0; rows; rows = tbody.rows[i]; i++) {
    //loops through cells
    for (var j = 1; col; col = rows.cells[j]; j++) {
        //gets cells of current row
        cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
        //gets cells of col 1
        ocells = rows.cells[j].getElementByTagName('td');

        while (rows.cells[j] === null) {
            //condition here>>
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="table">
    <table name="tbody" id="tbody1">
        <tr> 
            <td>col1 Val1</td>
            <td>col2 Val2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>col1 Val3</td>
            <td>col2 Val4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would rethink the necessity to loop over everything to do this:

If you made the table (or it is generated), add a class to each cell in column 2.

Let's call this class: "column-2-cell"

Now using jQuery:

```
$('.column-2-cell:empty').addClass('empty');
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ubz6w/

Optionally you can also use this with jQuery:

```
$('tr').each(function(i) {
    var column2cell = $($(this).children('td')[1]);
    if (column2cell.text() == "") {
        column2cell.css('background-color', 'red');        
    }
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ubz6w/1

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP is looking for a javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this. This will set the background of the second `column` if it is empty.

```
var tbody = document.getElementsByName("tbody")[0];

for (var i = 0, rows; rows = tbody.rows[i]; i++) {
    if(rows.cells[1].innerHTML == "") {
        rows.cells[1].className += "highlight";
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vXYcy/)